# Uninitialized constant error while upgrading Rails (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I am trying to upgrade Rails from 5.2 to 6.1. That requires i18n to be greater than equal to 1.6 (rails -> activesupport -> i18n), so upgraded the same from 0.7, but keep getting this error.

```
NameError: uninitialized constant I18n::HashRefinements
Did you mean?  HashWithIndifferentAccess
```

Any solution for this? Any kind of suggestion will be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

> > require 'i18n/core_ext/hash'

Where ever you are using I18n.